# Unable to push data into the firebase database from react native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to use firebase and have been successful in implementing authentication apis. But i am unable to push the data to firbase database. 
Here is my code :

```
//import firebase from '../../firebase/firebase';
 import * as firebase from 'firebase';

 export default class Home extends React.Component {
   onAddPressed() {
    var p = firebase.database().ref().push().set({
        title: "Hello World!",
        author: "Simon",
        location: "Germany",
        city: "Muenster",
        state: "Germany",
        zip: 48155
    });
    console.log(p);
    p.then(function () {
        console.log("success")
        }, function () {
        console.log('rejected promise')
    }).catch((e) => console.log(e))
}

 render(){
   return (
        <View>
            <Text>This is Home</Text>

            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.onAddPressed.bind(this)}>
                <Text> add User  </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
  }
```

When I click on Text, a Promise P is returned, but it never gets resolved or rejected. So basically nothing happens (No error also). 
What am i doing wrong?

**Q2.** Where should I import the firebase from ? There are two options :

**1.**  `import * as firebase from 'firebase';`

**2.**  `import firebase from '../../firebase/firebase` (my singleton class)

**EDIT** 
my database rules are as follows:

```
 {
  "rules": {
  ".read": "auth == null",
  ".write": "auth == null"
 }
}
```

I have made a singleton firebase class in which I have initialized my firebase

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default firebase;
```

After debugging I got to know that when I am doing the following, the `firebase` is not defined.

```
firebase
.database()
.ref("list/")
.push({
  title: "Title",
  createAt: new Date().toString()
});
```

Comment: Are you sure your database __RULES__ set to public?

Comment: Have you initialized your firebase in app? `firebase.initializeApp({ apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com" })`

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell exact solution without clearly defined issue. Have you initialized your firebase in app or are you **RULES** are set to public?

Try following code to test firebase, if its work then you can modify this code according to your needs. Its working in my case. Don't forget to set your set your database **RULES** to public for **testing**.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

const config = {
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  authDomain: "authDomain",
  databaseURL: "databaseURL",
  projectId: "projectId",
  storageBucket: "projectId",
  messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase
  .database()
  .ref("list/")
  .push({
    title: "Title",
    createAt: new Date().toString()
  });
```

**RULES**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}
```

> I will not recommend these rules settings, use it for testing purpose.

Comment: I have tried your code but it Doesn't work. I have edited my question. please see to it.

Comment: I tested my code before posting here.
Are you on android or ios?  Is allow arbitrary loads set to true in your .plist?

Comment: I am building for android .

Comment: I have made a new RN project using `react-native init` .In constructor of App.js I have added your code. Rules are also same as specified by you. But still unable to write anything to firebase database.

Comment: Are you sure about config settings? Try `firebase.database().ref("list/").push(...)`  in `compnentDidMount`. Sorry I can not help you more than that.

Comment: let me know when you fix your issue.

Comment: It is working fine. I was running it on my office PC, maybe there was some issue there. But in my personal PC, it is working fine.